# which query is faster? and why?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I receive a question.

1. `select * form table whereIn(id, array(1,2,3,4))`
2. `select * form table where(id=1) or where (id=2) or where (id=3)`

which query is faster? and Why.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: This syntax is not MySQL and doesn't look like any other sql I am familiar with.  Please ask about actual working queries.

Comment: It is documented that MySQL can optimize the IN clause under certain situations so IN would be faster. But there is only one way to find out.